# angular.js chrome Access-Control-Allow-Origin

Tags: angularjs

I'm trying to use an Angular.js service to get a JSON from my REST service made with Jersey/Spring.

When i'm using firefox, it works fine, but when i go to Chrome i got the message:

```
XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://localhost:8080/VirtualLawyerPj/services/timeoftheday/asjson/tue. Origin http://localhost:8090 is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin.
```

Here's my service code:

```
angular.module('myAppServices', ['ngResource']).
factory('Time', function($resource){
    return $resource('http://localhost:port/VirtualLawyerPj/services/timeoftheday/asjson/tue',{port:":8080"}, {
        query: {method:'GET', params:{}, isArray:false}
    });
});
```

Someone had the same problem? 
How did you got this working?

Thanks.

Comment: Start chrome from the command line and add the `--disable-web-security` flag.

`/path/to/chrome/chrome --disable-web-security`. It's great for testing

Comment: It worked for tests! But how about production? I'm starting a new project and feel a little bit scarred about this "issue" in Angular.js

Comment: It's not an issue with angular.js, but a normal browser and XMLHttpRequest issue.  It should work in production, since you won't be on localhost. But I don't really know much about CORS, you'll have to wait for someone else.

Comment: Worst case you can always proxy requests at the server.

Comment: See
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18053547/angularjs-failed-to-load-resource-origin-null-is-not-allowed-by-access-control

=>
Chrome.exe --allow-file-access-from-files

Answer (score 2):

The CORS solution is described at [html5rocks](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/cors/) tutorial. Worked for me.

Comment: Here in combination with AngularJS. http://nils-blum-oeste.net/cors-api-with-oauth2-authentication-using-rails-and-angularjs/

Answer (score 2):

I am still learning Angular myself, but using the $location service to get the current url host and port makes things easier when moving code between environments. Incidentally, this has also helped me overcome the issue you describe.

```
angular.module('myAppServices', ['ngResource']).
factory('Time', ['$location', function($location) {
  var url = 'http://:host::port/VirtualLawyerPj/services/timeoftheday/asjson/tue';
  var params = {
    host: $location.host(),
    port: $location.port()
  };
  var actions = {
    query: {method:'GET', isArray:false}
  };
  return $resource(url, params, actions);
}])
```

Answer (score 2):

I have an Apache server running on port 80 and a REST webservice on port 8889, same server. I tried this solution but didn't work:

```
    myApp.config(['$httpProvider', function($httpProvider) {
        $httpProvider.defaults.useXDomain = true;
        delete $httpProvider.defaults.headers.common['X-Requested-With'];
    }]);
```

The only way I figured out to get this to work was:

1. On services.js file:

   ```
   angular.module('mirthServices', ['ngResource']).
       factory('Cs', function ($resource) {
           return $resource('http://localhost/rest/cs/id/:csId');
       });
   ```
2. On the apache proxy.conf file:

   ```
   ProxyPass /rest http://localhost:8889/REST
   ProxyPassReverse /rest http://localhost:8889/REST
   ```

Comment: I solved my problem modifying the server response, but you need to control also the webservice, of course.
I added the Access-Control-Allow-Origin: * header.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem by changing in apache in file httpd.conf :

```
....
<Directory>
    .....
    Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
</Directory>
```

I added the line Header set, hope this help someone