# Angularjs: Failed to load resource: Origin null is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin in chrome

Tags: google-chrome, angularjs

I am using AngularJS v1.1.5 and try to load templates using ng-include,

```
Failed to load resource: Origin null is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin. file:///E:/apps/partials/holidayList.html

XMLHttpRequest cannot load file:///E:/apps/partials/holidayList.html. Origin null is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin.
```

i have already tried command line options for chrome, it not working for me to disable the policy and i don't want command line options, Any thing i need to edit in anguarjs file

Comment: Use a Webserver to serve the files. Something like apache. Then you can access the files via http://localhost/.../holidayList.ht

Comment: Or Start chrome with the Parameter --allow-running-insecure-content

Comment: I don't want to use Web Server

Comment: Hi tschiela 
Your command is not working

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to open your chrome with following command. (Press window+R)

```
Chrome.exe --allow-file-access-from-files
```

Note : Your chrome must not be open. When you run this command chrome will open automatically.

If you are entering this command in command prompt then select your chrome installation directory then use this command.